# "If There Are" versus "If There Be"

Tags: tense, subjunctives

I have begun to understand the subjunctive mood, but I have one question whose answer eludes me notwithstanding the means of the Web: "why do people say 'if there is' and 'if there are' when the proper subjunctive tensing would render 'if there be'?"

Am I correct in labeling these phrases improper/proper subjunctives?

Comment: Because the "proper" subjunctive mood (not tense) is falling out of favor.

Comment: English does not have a subjunctive mood. So, you should label them simply as preposition phrases.